# Timeseries data with arbitrary number of rows

Tags: cassandra

I'm currently working on a POC using cassandra.

What I want to do:
There are a variable number of sensors (never known up front) and each sensor will provide some value a few times a second. What I want to do is the calculate averages, min, max, velocity for every second, minute, hour etc.

How I have modeled my data:
For have multiple column families; raw, avg-5-second, avg-60-second etc. The rowid is the sensor id, e.g. machinex:memory. The columname is the timestamp and the column value is the measurement.

What I have so far:
I have create a system where I generate data for a single sensor (so single rowid). And I have some tasks that take a slice of data for that given rowid and store the results in the aggregated columnfamilies.

example:

Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test-cluster", "localhost:9160");
    Keyspace keyspace = createKeyspace(cluster, "Measurements");

```
String machine1 = "foo:dev:192.168.1.1:5701";
String rowId = machine1 + ":operationCount";

DatapointRepository rawRepo = new DatapointRepository(cluster, keyspace, "Measurements");
DatapointRepository avgSecondRepo = new DatapointRepository(cluster, keyspace, "averageSecond");
DatapointRepository avgFiveSecondRepo = new DatapointRepository(cluster, keyspace, "averageFiveSeconds");
DatapointRepository maxFiveSecondRepo = new DatapointRepository(cluster, keyspace, "maxFiveSeconds");

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new RollupRunnable(
        rawRepo,
        avgSecondRepo,
        rowId,
        "average 1 second",
                new AggregateFunctionFactory(AverageFunction.class)),
        0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new RollupRunnable(
        avgSecondRepo,
        avgFiveSecondRepo,
        rowId,
        "average 5 seconds",
                new AggregateFunctionFactory(AverageFunction.class)),
        0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new RollupRunnable(
        avgSecondRepo,
        maxFiveSecondRepo,
        rowId,
        "maximum 5 seconds",
                new AggregateFunctionFactory(MaximumFunction.class)),
        0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

new GenerateMeasurementsThread(rawRepo, machine1).start();

Thread.sleep(30000);

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("average seconds:");
print(avgSecondRepo, startTime, endTime, machine1 + ":operationCount");
System.out.println("average 5 seconds:");
print(avgFiveSecondRepo, startTime, endTime, machine1 + ":operationCount");
System.out.println("max 5 seconds:");
print(maxFiveSecondRepo, startTime, endTime, machine1 + ":operationCount");


System.out.println("finished");
System.exit(0);
```

So everything works fine if I have a single sensor (so a single row id), or if I know up front which sensors there are. The problem is that I have a variable number of sensor and new sensors could appear at any given moment and old sensor could stop sending data.

My big question is: how can I figure out which sensors are available within a given time period? Once I know that, I can create a aggregate tasks per sensor.

Answer (score 0):

"My big question is: how can I figure out which sensors are available within a given time period? Once I know that, I can create a aggregate tasks per sensor."

So far what you have done is to index data by sensor THEN timestamp (sensorId=rowId, timestamp = column name)

What you want to do now is index by time first. I'm afraid you need to create extra column family:

```
rowId = xxx // whatever value, doest not really matter

column name = timestamp

column value = sensor ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have implemented your suggestion and it works, apart from one bug.

If there are multiple sensor datapoints for the same 'time' only the name of the last saved datapoint is shown. This is logical because the row id is a constant (in my case it is the string "name") and the timestamp is the column id and the sensor name is the value.

Answer (score 0):

@userxxxx

"I have implemented your suggestion and it works, apart from one bug. If there are multiple sensor datapoints for the same 'time' only the name of the last saved datapoint is shown."

Easy fix:

```
rowId = xxx // whatever value, doest not really matter

column name = composite of(timestamp,sensorId)

column value = nothing
```

By setting column name as composite of timestamp and sensorId, you'll cover the case of having multiple sensors at exactly the same time.

Since the sensorID information is stored directly in the column, you no longer need column value. This is called a **value-less** column family

CQL script to create such table

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_index_by_date
(

   row_id text, // whatever
   date timestamp,
   sensor_id bigint,
   PRIMARY KEY(rowId,date,sensor_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented this solution. 

I have not used Cassandra before, so I'm just beginning to understand the possibilities.